# change cells text in a jqGrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

i have a colModel looks like this:

```
    { name: 'TypeId', index: 'TypeId', align: 'left',
 width: 50, editable: true, edittype: "select", sortable: false,
 hidden: false, jsonmap: 'InspectionTypeId' },
```

how can i change the cells text not changing the value?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way, you can define a [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) (and unformatter) such that they will return the value that you need. Formatter will change the displayed text, and unformatter will convert this text back to the real value.